# Robolectric shadow: calls only working within test class

Tags: android, logging, shadow, robolectric

I am trying to test a wrapper we wrote for the `android.util.Log` framework.

My shadowing code and test looks like this:

```
@Implements(Log.class)
public static class ShadowLog {
    @Implementation
    public static int i(java.lang.String tag, java.lang.String msg) {
        System.out.println("[SHADOW] [" + tag + "] " + msg);
        return 0;
    }
}
```

The test class contains the appropriate tags:

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
@Config(shadows = {LnTest.ShadowLog.class})` tags.
```

This is the test:

```
@Test
public void foobar() {
    Ln.i("LN_TAG", "LN_MSG");
    Log.i("DIRECT_TAG", "DIRECT_MSG");
}
```

NOTE: `Ln` is our wrapper for Log, which I want to test. It itself contains calls to `Log.i`, `Log.d`, etc...

The ouput of the test is:

> > [SHADOW] [DIRECT_TAG] DIRECT_MSG

- So I see a shadow `println` statement from my direct `Log` call, but I don't see any statements from the call to our custom wrapper...
- So it seems that my shadowing is only working for direct calls from *within my test*, but not for calls from other classes...

**Can somebody explain why this isn't working and how I could fix it?**